# Orientation and vector product

Tags: vector-spaces

If $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ are the ordered orthonormal basis of 3- dimensional Euclidean vector space V and A is the permutation operator defined by: $$A(e_1) = e_2, A(e_2)=e_3, A(e_3) =  e_1$$ Prove that this is an orthogonal linear map with det(A) = 1, so it is a rotation. Also find an orthonormal basis of V so that this is rotation has normal form.

Hint given: Find the axis of rotation and then orthonormal basis.